# Converting a public method into a private method

Tags: java, unit-testing

I recently refactored some code which converted a public method that was only being used in conjure with another public method, into one call.

```
public class service() {
  public String getAuthenticatedUserName() {
    return SecurityContext.getName();
  }

  public getIdentityUserIdByUsername(String username) {
    return db.getUser(username).getId();
  }
}
```

which was being utilised in a few other classes as `service.getIdentityUserIdByUsername(service.getUsername())`, which seemed redudant. A new method was created combining the two calls.

```
public getIdentityUserId() {
  return getIdentityUserIdByUsername(getUsername());
}
```

The `getIdentityUserIdByUsername()` is still being utilised in other classes without the need for `getUsername()`. However, the `getUserName()` method is no longer used in other classes.

My example is much simpler than the implementation, the method has test coverage that is a bit awkward to do (mocking static classes without Powermock and a bit of googling etc). In the future it's likely we will need the `getUsername()` method, and the method will not change.

It was suggested in code review that the `getUsername()` method should now be private due to it not being called anywhere else. This would require the explicit tests for the method be removed/commented out which seems like it would be repeated effort to rewrite or ugly to leave commented out code.

Is it best practice to change the method to private or leave it public because it has explicit coverage and you might need it in the future?

Comment: You can make methods package-private to still make tests in the same package space able to see them

Comment: @cricket_007 Is that not just 'cheating' so you can get the tests working, setting a method to protected for testing purposes always has a smell to me

Comment: You can always expose it later if needed. However, you should be focused on the type's responsibility, and the behaviors needed to carry out that responsibility. If access to a username is defined in the contract/expected usage, then it would be expected to expose a `getUsername()`, since the type was designed to allow access to such. If making the method private requires a lot of work, **deprecate the method** & warn about future removal. You'd be reducing future usage of `getUsername()`, so if you do commit to making it private, it won't be as much work.

Comment: if you clean your storage for tests, i.e. the user ID is always the same when testing the `getIdentityUserId`, then there should be no need to test the `getUserName` and the test can be removed. But, as you say there's a possibility of using `getUsername` somewhere else than it should stay as public. In other words, it's a getter method which mostly are public and adds that functionality to the service, which could be used later in other services. For future usages, leaving it public reduces the need of changing that service.

Comment: @itwasntme I don't think he's testing `getUsername()`, rather there exists tests which use/mock it, and removing `getUsername()` would break those tests.

Comment: K I got it. I consider the service methods as a part of API of an app, having well designed service with "currently" unused methods (unused, could be used earlier but no longer) isn't a very bad think, because later when working in other class and using that service it already provides me a set of methods which could be used. In more complex situation, not having such methods could lead to reading and understanding the service to add the needed method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it best practice to change the method to private or leave it public because it has explicit coverage and you might need it in the future?

IMO, you are asking the wrong question.  So called "best practice" doesn't come into it.  (Read the references below!)

The real question is which of the alternatives is / are most likely to be best for you. That is really for you to decide.  Not us.

The alternatives are:

1. You could remove the test case for the private method.
2. You could comment out the test case.
3. You could fix the test case so that it runs with the private version of the method.
4. You could leave the method as `public`.

To make a *rational* decision, you need to consider the technical and non-technical pros and cons of each alternative ... *in the context of your project*.  But don't be too concerned about making the wrong decision.  In the big picture, it is highly unlikely that making the wrong choice will have serious consequences.

Finally, I would advise to avoid dismissing options just because they are "code smell".  That phrase has the same issue as "best practice".  It causes you to dismiss valid options based on generalizations ... and current opinions (even fashions) on what is good or bad "practice".

---

Since you want someone else's opinion ("best practice" is just opinion!), mine is that all of the alternatives are valid.  But my vote would be to leave the method as `public`.  It is the least amount of work, and an unused method in an API does little harm.  And as you say, there is a *reasonable* expectation that the method will be used in the future.

You don't need to agree with your code reviewer.  (But this is not worth making enemies over ...)

---

References:

- [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) by James Bach
- [There is no such thing as "Best Practices": Context Matters.](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/there-is-no-such-thing-as-best-practices-context-matters/) by Ted Neward.

Comment: He could also deprecate the method to discourage future use & expose the alternative method. No need to commit to a decision now. If he decides to change accessibility it later, he could sleep soundly knowing he prevented further spread of usage. He'd decrease the amount of effort it takes to reduce accessibility. Not sure if that's an option you'd suggest in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I agree there's no 'correct' solution, but all my opinions are regurgitations of what I've been told over the last few years, so it's nice to hear some new ones. I was of the same opinion as you, but my thought of it's the least work to change it and it doesn't matter - felt like I was being dismissive or lazy, unsure if I was missing something -  thanks again :)

Comment: @VinceEmigh - I thought about it, and I don't think deprecation achieves the OP's goal.  If the goal was to get rid of the method, it can be removed right now.  Corey is saying that he thinks that it will be useful ... so discouraging its use is counter-productive

Answer (score 0):

It can make sense to want to test private methods. The industry standard way to do this, which has quite some advantages, is this:

- Ensure that the test code lives in the same package as the code it tries to test. That doesn't mean same directory; for example, have `src/main/java/pkg/MyClass.java` and `src/test/java/pkg/MyClassTest.java`.
- Make your private methods package private instead. Annotate them with `@VisibleForTesting` (from [guava](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html)) if you want some record of this.

Separately from this, the entry space for public methods (public in the sense of: This is part of my API and defines the access points where external code calls my code) is normally some list of entrypoints.. if you have it at all. More often there is no such definition at all. One could say that all public methods in all public types implicitly form the list (i.e. that the keyword `public` implies that it is for consumption by external code), which then by tautology decrees that any public method has the proper signature. Not a very useful definition. In practice, the keyword `public` does not have to mean 'this is API accessible'. Various module systems (such as jigsaw or OSGi) have solutions for this, generally by letting you declare certain packages as actually public.

With such tooling, 'treeshaking' your public methods to point out that they need no longer be public makes sense. Without them... you can't really do this. There is such a notion as 'this method is never called in my codebase, but it is made available to external callers; callers that I don't have available here, and the point is that this is released, and there are perhaps projects that haven't even started being written yet which are intended to call this'.

Assuming you do have the tree-shaking concept going, you can still leave them in for that 'okay maybe not today but tomorrow perhaps' angle. If that applies, leave it in. If you can't imagine any use case where external code needs access to it, just delete it. If it really needs to be recovered, hey, there's always the history in version control.

Comment: I most likely couldn't justify pulling in a new dependancy for this, but noted for the future. I mentioned this in a comment, but setting methods to protected just for testing purposes always felt like a code smell to me, but I might be wrong. Never heard of Treeshaking will look into that. Thanks for your response, it's tough because it's likely it will be needed but could be months until x feature is implemented that needs it. But I'm at the perspective of, what's the harm of leaving it public? Does it outweigh the however slight inconvenience it may cause in the future?

Comment: If you feel the need to test private methods, chances are you are violating SRP, and you should decompose your type. You should be testing from a client perspective, to ensure the type is safe to use by other types/clients. If you test private methods, you're either excessively testing, or those private methods should really be public methods of a different type (separate responsibility).

Comment: @Corey not 'protected', _package_ (which is what you get when you have no access modifier at all). package is generally fine; unlike protected, it counts as 'internal' (excluded from javadoc by default, for example).

Answer (score 0):

If the method is a `public static` then you can leave it as is because there is no impact of it being public. It is aside effect free method, it being exposed will never cause any harm.

If it is a object level public method then -

1) Keep it if it is like an API. It has well defined input, output and delivers a well defined functionality and has tests associated with it. It being public doesn't harm anything.

2) Make it private immediately if it has side effects. If it causes others methods to behave differently because it changes the state of the object then it is harmful being public.